# Quitar etiquetas izquierdas y derechas de Plotly que usa facet_row o usar make_subplots en Python

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

Estoy usando Plotly.express, plotly.subplots y plotly.graph_objs para visualizar unos gráficos que varían de acuerdo a unos datos (data) que le paso, pero que aquí coloco en codigo duro para ahorrarme codigo, sea más legible y simplificado.

Lo que quiero lograr es un gráfico como el que muestro enseguida (es una imagen editada), con una sola etiqueta en los ejes-y "Value", sin etiquetas del lado derecho, el eje-x se quedaría como está con la etiqueta "Timeline" y que el eje-x no separe en multiplos de 2 los valores (e integrarlo con las lineas desde -1 hasta el ultimo valor del eje-x, explico al final):
[image: primer gráfico]

1ro. Cuando uso plotly.express este es el código:

```
import plotly.express as px

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    "Name": [
        "Lamp_D_Rq", "Status", "Status", "HMI",
        "Lck_D_RqDrv3", "Lck_D_RqDrv3", "Lck_D_RqDrv3",
        "Lck_D_RqDrv3", "Lamp_D_Rq", "Lamp_D_Rq",
        "Lamp_D_Rq", "Lamp_D_Rq",
    ],
    "Value": [0, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3],
    "Gage": [
        "F1", "H1", "H3", "H3", "H3",
        "F1", "H3", "F1", "F1", "H3",
        "F1", "H3",
    ],
    "Id_Par": [0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
}

signals_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

signals_df['Count'] = signals_df.groupby('Id_Par').cumcount().add(1).mask(signals_df['Id_Par'].eq(0), 0)
signals_df['Sub'] = signals_df.index - signals_df['Count']
id_par_prev = signals_df['Id_Par'].unique()
id_par = np.delete(id_par_prev, 0)
signals_df['Prev'] = [1 if x in id_par else 0 for x in signals_df['Id_Par']]

print(signals_df)

fig = px.line(
    signals_df,
    y="Value",
    x="Sub",
    color="Name",
    hover_data=["Gage"],
    custom_data=["Gage"],
    markers=True,
    height=500,
    render_mode="svg",
    facet_row="Name"
)

fig.update_traces(line={"shape": 'hv'})
fig.update_traces(
    hovertemplate="<br>".join([
        "Gage: %{customdata[0]}",
    ]))

fig.update_layout(
        hovermode="x",
        title="Saving/Loss diagram",
        legend_title="CAN Singals",)

fig.update_xaxes(matches='x')

fig.show(config={'displaylogo': False})
```

En la ejecución de este primer código, me sale lo siguiente, la etiqueta Value repetida por subtrama y con los nombres empalmados del lado derecho, incluso estos valores tiene los nombres más pequeños que encontré, hay nombres mucho más extensos, es por eso que los quiero eliminar, pero no encuentro la opción y los valores del eje-x separados por multiplos de 2, quisiera presentarlos 1x1:
[image: segundo gráfico]

2do. Cuando uso plotly.subplots y plotly.graph_objs el código es:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objs as go

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    "Name": [
        "Lamp", "Status", "Status", "M1",
        "Lock", "Lock", "Lock",
        "Lock", "Lamp", "Lamp",
        "Lamp", "Lamp",
    ],
    "Value": [0, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3],
    "Gage": [
        "A1", "B1", "B3", "B3", "B3",
        "A1", "B3", "A1", "A1", "B3",
        "A1", "B3",
    ],
    "Id_Par": [0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
}

signals_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

signals_df['Count'] = signals_df.groupby('Id_Par').cumcount().add(1).mask(signals_df['Id_Par'].eq(0), 0)
signals_df['Sub'] = signals_df.index - signals_df['Count']
id_par_prev = signals_df['Id_Par'].unique()
id_par = np.delete(id_par_prev, 0)
signals_df['Prev'] = [1 if x in id_par else 0 for x in signals_df['Id_Par']]
print(signals_df)

names_signals = signals_df['Name'].unique()

fig = make_subplots(rows=len(names_signals), cols=1,
                    shared_xaxes=True,
                    vertical_spacing=0.02)

for i, name_signal in enumerate(names_signals):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=signals_df["Sub"],
                             y=signals_df["Value"],
                             line_shape='hv',
                             # facet_row="Name")
                             ))
fig.update_layout(
        hovermode="x",
        title="Saving/Loss diagram",
        legend_title="CAN Singals",)

fig.update_xaxes(matches='x')
fig.show(config={'displaylogo': False})
```

En la ejecución del segundo código que es una prueba de lo que he estado haciendo para ver si me resulta mas sencillo visualizar los datos, pero me da un error de que no encuentra el parametro facet_row, cuando lo descomentarizo y si, ya busqué en el help de Scatter y no encuentro algo parecido:
[image: tercer gráfico]

En este caso, estoy usando esto porque al revisar la documentación de Plotly me dí cuenta que el `update_trace`, `update_layout`, etc es donde se puede editar y actualizar estos parametros del gráfico y aqui como usa `add_trace` al parecer es un poco diferente, pero necesito primero separar el gráfico por subtramas y no encuentro como.

En ambos casos el objetivo es, de unas señales de un circuito, separar los valores y graficos por nombres y subtramas, es decir, graficar como varian y se presentan los valores en una linea de tiempo de acuerdo a su nombre y pintados en diferentes subtramas.

Respecto a las lineas que empiezan desde -1 y terminan hasta el ultimo valor de las señales, intenté lo siguiente, y no me lo acepta porque quiere forzosamente que le pase una columna del dataframe `signals_df`, pero primero quiero lograr encontrar los parámetros que me permitan graficar las subtramas con una sola etiqueta en el eje-y izquierdo y eliminar los nombres del lado derecho y el eje-x lo separe 1x1, para después seguir con esto, que en realidad me sirvió muy bien, en una aplicación de escritorio que realicé con Matplotlib, pero este caso tampoco sabría como mandar llamar estos valores, ya que he intentado meterlo en variables y asignarlo a "x" y "y" de px.line y no funciona:

```
x= np.hstack([-1, data.index.values, len(signals_df) - 1])
y= np.hstack([0, data.values, data.iloc[-1]])
```

Espero haber sido explicita y me puedan ayudar, les agradezco mucho.